# Nivo Slider is not centered

Tags: jquery, html, css, plugins, nivo-slider

[image]Check out http://waterski.allthingswebdesign.com/index.php/site/index and you can see that my Nivo Slider is not centered on the background. I can't figure out why this is. (ignore the 2nd and 3rd pictures as I know they are not the correct size, but the 1st one is).

Comment: The slider appears to be centered for me. What browser are you in? Or are you talking about the picture within the slider?

Comment: Just tested in chrome, firefox, safari and opera... the slider is centered. The images are aligned top left just like they are told to, because they aren't the exact same size as the slider.

Comment: Agreed with Jackson, it is centered.  If you are using IE, it could be a syntax error that is throwing it off.  I know that if I don't call <header> right in IE they won't center a thing.  Using Chrome here.

Comment: I've edit it to show a picture of what I mean. I'm seeing this in chrome and firefox.

Comment: Yeah, looks centered. And using the elemnt inspector. Teh calculations also add up. It's centered. I could only assume you mean the photos inside, they aren't because they are, all three of them, not the correct size

Comment: @Jackson Gariety - Yes I mean the photos inside. Sorry for misclarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options...

a: Do what the software was designed for and use the exact size of images.

b: remove the border style and drop shadow from the slider itself, and apply it to the image. Then use some css styling to center the image.

```
#slider img{
    margin-left:0 auto;
    margin-right:0 auto;
}
```

Essentially, hide all traces of the slider div and just center the images inside. It would be odd, but if that's what you're going for, more power too ya.

Comment: I guess I didn't clarify this in the question, but the pictures will eventually all be the same size. These are just my testing photos that I had laying around. If I make all the photos the same size, do you think that will solve the issue?

Comment: Yes, yes it will. That is my first answer, answer a. Make the images the exact size of the #slider.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I should have just done it the right way to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

Its because Nivo Slider here has a specific width and height. None of your images fill it. *None* of your images.

The first image almost does it but since it doesnt, it leaves some space in the right side and at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the image size, the nivoSlider uses it as Background Image,
so there is no redimension as in img tag or center.
The image is 830x302 px and the nivoSlider container is 838x311 px, 
so that's the diference you see.